# select-from-where procedure using R

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, sqldf

I have two dataframes, here's the first:

```
df <- data.frame(p=letters[1:3],y1=c(2,4,3))
df
  p y1
1 a 2
2 b 4
3 c 3
```

and the second one:

```
df2 <- data.frame(p=rep(letters[1:3],c(3,2,4)),y2=c(3,1,1,4,3,4,3,3,1),d=rep(1,length=9))
df2
  p y2 d
1 a 3 1
2 a 1 1
3 a 1 1
4 b 4 1
5 b 3 1
6 c 4 1
7 c 3 1
8 c 3 1
9 c 1 1
```

What I want to do is get those lines in `df2`, where for each value of `p`(a,b,c etc.) where `d=1` (which in this case are all rows), `y2` is bigger than `y1` grouped by `p` in `df`.

Because this explanation probably doesn't make sense, the two lines that need to be kicked: **line 1** in `df2`, because for `a`, `y2=3` is greater than `y1=2` in `df`, and **line 6**, because for `c` in `df2`, `y` has value 4, but the value for `c` in `df` is 3.

Since I'm working with data.tables, a "data.table-solution" would be nice, maybe something like:

```
setkey(df2,d)
df2[1,y>??,by="p"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `merge` before subsetting.

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
merge(data.table(df1,key='p'),
      data.table(df2,key='p'))[d==1 & y2 > y1]
   p y1 y2 d
1: a  2  3 1
2: c  3  4 1
```

Using `base merge`:

```
subset(merge(df1,df2), d==1 & y2 > y1)
  p y1 y2 d
1 a  2  3 1
6 c  3  4 1
```

**EDIT**

For the `data.table` solution , here is better to use a join Y[X] , looking up Y's rows using  X's key.(LEFT OUTER JOIN)

```
DF2 <- data.table(df2,key='p')
DF1 <- data.table(df1,key='p')
DF2[DF1][d==1 & y2 > y1]

   p y2 d y1
1: a  3 1  2
2: c  4 1  3
```

Comment: you should use the `[` operator instead of `merge` - assuming `df` and `df2` are `data.table`'s with key `p`: `df[df2][d == 1 & y2 > y1]`

Comment: @Macs yes it is, but `[` is faster, shorter to write and more in line with `data.table` philosophy

Answer (score 1):

Similar to rmk but using plyr:

```
library(plyr)
dfa <- data.frame(p=letters[1:3],y1=c(2,4,3))
dfa

dfb <- data.frame(p=rep(letters[1:3],c(3,2,4)),y2=c(3,1,1,4,3,4,3,3,1),d=rep(1,length=9))
dfb

dfb <- join(dfa, dfb, by = "p", type = "left", match = "all")
dfb

dfb$z <- ifelse(dfb$y2>dfb$y1, 1, 0)
dfb[dfb$z==1, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df3 <- merge(df,df2,by=1)
> df3
  p y1 y2 d
1 a  2  3 1
2 a  2  1 1
3 a  2  1 1
4 b  4  4 1
5 b  4  3 1
6 c  3  4 1
7 c  3  3 1
8 c  3  3 1
9 c  3  1 1


> df3[df3$y2>df3$y1 & df3$d==1,]
  p y1 y2 d
1 a  2  3 1
6 c  3  4 1
```